# Error AADSTS65001 but no consent prompt for just one user

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am writing a C# .NET app. It is connected to our service on Azure which is configured for using AAD. In turn, our service tries to make calls to Exchange via EWS.

This all worked fine for me until we recently deployed our service bits to a new Azure web app with new app registrations. They are all configured correctly and other developers on our team can authenticate with the service and use it as expected.

When I try to connect to the service, I get the following error:
AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '61a8b794-7f67-4a01-9094-fcdd45693eaa'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
Trace ID: ece7c5d0-2ecb-4096-a87a-2cd33271d65d
Correlation ID: 093b5935-3b06-4d76-91a9-6619bc179544
Timestamp: 2017-02-09 23:19:28Z

The consent prompt never appeared for me when trying to connect after deploying the new service.

I'm not sure what it is about my user account that causes this error to occur (it happens on multiple machines with my account) while others can connect successfully.

Here’s some of the code used to acquire the token in the service:

```
var bootstrapContext = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().BootstrapContext as System.IdentityModel.Tokens.BootstrapContext;

var upn = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn);
var email = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email);
var userName =  upn != null ? upn.Value : email?.Value;

accessToken = bootstrapContext.Token;

ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential("61a8b794-7f67-4a01-9094-fcdd45693eaa", appKey);
UserAssertion assertion = new UserAssertion(accessToken, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", userName);

AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/microsoft.onmicrosoft.com");
AuthResult = authContext.AcquireToken("https://outlook.office365.com", clientCred, assertion);
```

Any ideas why I wouldn't get the consent prompt, but other users on my team have?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description, you are developing multi-tier application using Azure AD.

Since you mentioned this issue was occurred after using the new app, did you config your new app as the `knownClientApplications` of your service app(61a8b794-7f67-4a01-9094-fcdd45693eaa)?

If yes, you should can give the consent for the service app when you sign-in your web app( refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#multi-tenant-applications-and-caching-access-tokens) about multi-tier applications).

The problem why only you get this issue may others have given the consent to this app before.

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

To clarify a bit further, we did not change the Azure AD app registration for the client, just gave it permissions to the new service (in addition to the previous service). The consent prompt that is generated is for granting permission to access the service via the client.

The knownClientApplications of the new service is correctly configured to contain the client app Id. Other users received the consent prompt after they logged into the updated client. I did not. It's the same client, the same (new) service, and all users receive the consent prompt except me.

Comment: Is it helpful to append the `prompt=consent` to force to grant the consent when you sign-in the client?

Comment: Unfortunately (seriously, as I would have liked to be able to root cause this issue), the problem does not repro anymore.

We introduced a new instance of the service with new app registrations and I received a consent prompt for the new version. Magically (and perplexingly), this appeared to also fix the problem with the previous version of the service, despite me never having consented to it.